# Vim: How to position the preview window?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

How do I open the preview window under the NERDTree window (i.e. vertically split NERDTree and open the preview window in the bottom part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible best guess

<kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The following setting can put a preview window on the bottom, it may help

```
set splitbelow
```